# Tidy R way to store a collection or vector for each line in a data.frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidy

What is the tidy way to store a collection (e.g. `c(...)`) for each record/line of a data.frame?

#### Example

Suppose we have `customers` in a dataframe, and want to add a collection of each customer's puchases to the customer data.frame?

```
customers <- data.frame(customer_number=c(1,2,3), stringsAsFactors = F)

#   customer_number
# 1               1
# 2               2
# 3               3


transactions <- data.frame(customer_number=c(3,3,1,1,3),
                           item=c("milkshake", "burger", "apple", "fries", "water"),
                           stringsAsFactors = F)

#   customer_number      item
# 1               3 milkshake
# 2               3    burger
# 3               1     apple
# 4               1     fries
# 5               3     water
```

Customer `1` bought items `c('apple', 'fries')`, customer `2` didn't buy anything, and customer `3` bought items `c('milkshake', 'burger', 'water')`

What is the best way to store this data in the `customers` table, that is, strictly with one row per customer?

#### Notes

- Basically trying to store a collection (e.g. `c(...)`) for each row of the data.frame.
- I have considered storing the collection as a comma-separated string, which doesn't seem too sensible
- I have considered creating more rows (effectively a left_join(transactions, customer), but the data makes a lot more sense when stored as one customer per line (since *all* other 20+ columns of the data fit that structure).
- The next step will be to analysis on the resulting data.frame (or data structure), so the approach should suit that use case (conversion to strings doesn't work well for this)

Comment: A "tidy" data frame is one observation per row and one column per variable. This means that if "item" is a variable then you should have one item per row and all that customer's data repeated.

Comment: @R.Schifini how about the numerical encoding approach (eg one hot encoding). I think it’s another possibility whilst maintaining one foe per customer)

Answer (score 2):

We can store the `item` as a `list`.

```
library(dplyr)

transactions %>%
  group_by(customer_number) %>%
  summarise(item = list(item)) %>%
  right_join(customers, by = 'customer_number')

#  customer_number  item     
#            <dbl> <list>   
#1               1 <chr [2]>
#2               2 <NULL>   
#3               3 <chr [3]>
```

However, I don't find it wrong storing it as a comma-separated string as well with `summarise(item = toString(item))`, we can always tidy it by using `separate_rows` later when needed.

Answer (score 1):

In the devel version of `dplyr`, we can `condense` the column and then do the join

```
library(dplyr)
transactions %>% 
     group_by(customer_number) %>% 
     condense(item) %>% 
     right_join(customers)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Rowwise:  customer_number
#  customer_number item     
#*           <dbl> <list>   
#1               1 <chr [2]>
#2               3 <chr [3]>
#3               2 <NULL>
```